# Can I accept a file via Drag & Drop from the Mac to the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios-simulator

For debugging purposes I want to accept a JSON file from the Mac via drag & drop in the iPad simulator.

I implemented `UIDropInteractionDelegate` and can successfully accept drops from the iPad Files app. But ideally I'd like to accept drops directly from the Mac.

Right now, when dragging a JSON file into the Simulator, the Files app is opened and handles the drop.

I doubt it's possible but if someone has any idea (even private API, since it's for debugging only), please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept dropped files in the iOS Simulator by configuring your app to open documents of type you want to import. You can do this via [CFBundleDocumentTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685) in your Info.plist, or by using the *Info* tab in your target's build settings. The UTI for JSON files should be `public.json`.

When you've configured your app to handle JSON files, simply implement [`application:openURL:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc) in your app delegate to actually handle the drop.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Works great, thanks. So I don't even need to implement `UIDropInteractionDelegate`.

Comment: Please don't ship this to the app store; your app will start showing up as accepting these random file types.